# Hive : Column data mismatch after left outer join?

Tags: hive, left-join, hiveql

I am facing strange behaviour as explained below.  I have tow hive table T1 and T2 , joined with LEFT OUTER JOIN ..I am  getting strange value for two columns t2c2    t2c3 of table T2 after join.

***See below complete detail :***

***Table T1 :***

```
create table T1 ( t1c1 int , t1c2 int , t1c3 int ) clustered by (t1c1) into 2 buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');

4    4    1
4    4    0
1    1    1
1    1    0
5    5    1
```

***Table T2:***

```
create table T2 ( t2c0 int , t2c1 int , t2c2 int , t2c3 int  ) clustered by ( t2c1) into 2 buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true'); ;

0    1    -1    3
0    1    0    0
0    4    6    6
0    4    1    6
1    1    0    2
1    4    3    5
1    4    2    5
```

***Query :***

```
select *
from T1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
T2 b
ON a.t1c2 = b.t2c1;
```

***Result set : (not expected )***

```
a.t1c1  a.t1c2  a.t1c3  b.t2c0  b.t2c1  b.t2c2  b.t2c3
4   4   1   1   4   4   3
4   4   1   0   4   4   6
4   4   1   1   4   4   2
4   4   1   0   4   4   1
4   4   0   1   4   4   3
4   4   0   0   4   4   6
4   4   0   1   4   4   2
4   4   0   0   4   4   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   -1
1   1   1   1   1   1   0
1   1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   1   1   -1
1   1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   1   1   0
5   5   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

***Error description  :***
values in result set b.t2c2 and  b.t2c3  are strange and not expected . -1 in b.t2c3 is no more belong to T2.t2c3 , and 4 in b.t2c2 is no more belong to T2.t2c2.
I am not sure whats wrong with.  Please help me to identify the issue and resolve it.

***Expected result  :***

```
1    1    1    0    1    -1    3
1    1    1    1    1    0    2
1    1    1    0    1    0    0
1    1    0    0    1    -1    3
1    1    0    1    1    0    2
1    1    0    0    1    0    0
4    4    1    1    4    3    5
4    4    1    0    4    6    6
4    4    1    1    4    2    5
4    4    1    0    4    1    6
4    4    0    1    4    3    5
4    4    0    0    4    6    6
4    4    0    1    4    2    5
4    4    0    0    4    1    6
5    5    1    <null>    <null>    <null>    <null>
```

but if i change query to below , it start giving correct result.

```
select *
from ( select * from T1) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( select * from T2) b
ON a.t1c2 = b.t2c1;
```